# put three controls in a row at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

How do you specify a layout to put three controls in a row at the bottom of the screen?  I would like a TextView aligned left and two buttons in a group centered.
Without the "spacer" view all three controls are aligned together on the left.  With the code posted I get close to what I want.  Is there a way to center the LinearLayout with the buttons?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" 
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:textStyle="bold" >
 </ListView>

 <!-- Row of buttons to control the display of the holdings -->
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:background="@color/btnarea"
     >
    <!--     setText here disables "selection" of items ???? -->
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectedWPs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ae6633"
        android:text="Selected: "
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <!--    spacer  ???? why doesn't center_horizontal work??? -->
    <View android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/btnarea" />

   <!--  how to center following ??? -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/buttonArea" 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="0"
       >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quitBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:background="#990000"
            android:onClick="quitBtnClicked"
            android:text="Quit"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <!--    spacer   -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/btnarea" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/copyBtn" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:background="#009900"
            android:onClick="copyBtnClicked"
            android:text="Copy"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried both solutions given below. Neither did what I wanted.
One positioned the three controls: left center and right.  The other spread the left most control across the whole screen and jammed the other two controls to the right side.

The first image is my attempt.

[image: This is my attempt]

[image: First layout]

[image: Second layout]

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </ListView>

    <!-- Row of buttons to control the display of the holdings -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#969696"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- setText here disables "selection" of items ???? -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedWPs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#ae6633"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Selected: "
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <!-- spacer  ???? why doesn't center_horizontal work??? -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="#a3a3a3" />

        <!-- how to center following ??? -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/quitBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#990000"
                android:onClick="quitBtnClicked"
                android:text="Quit"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <!-- spacer -->

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#d5d5d5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/copyBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="copyBtnClicked"
                android:text="Copy"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

```
           <Button
                android:id="@+id/copyBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="copyBtnClicked"
                android:text="Copy"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#969696"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- setText here disables "selection" of items ???? -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedWPs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:background="#ae6633"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Selected: "
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <!-- spacer  ???? why doesn't center_horizontal work??? -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:background="#a3a3a3" />

        <!-- how to center following ??? -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.70"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/quitBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#990000"
                android:onClick="quitBtnClicked"
                android:text="Quit"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <!-- spacer -->

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#d5d5d5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/copyBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:onClick="copyBtnClicked"
                android:text="Copy"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#d5d5d5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you say what you changed and why you changed it?

Comment: @NormR i changed `linearLayout1` visible al things. i did't set specific width only changed the weight to display.

Comment: @NormR check my edit in that button hash two weight so only i edited check out.

Comment: I deleted the weight=0 line and tested with the weight=1 line.  The results are shown in the images above.  It didn't do what I am looking for.

Comment: @NormR from that images which is your requirement.

Comment: The first one is close, except the two buttons are not centered.

Comment: @NormR Check my second edit.I posted last layout. Try it and you need more adjustment just change that weight.

Comment: @Tamilian Thanks for trying.  I took your latest post and tried many combinations with it.  None were much better than my original attempt. I wasted too much time using trial and error technique to get a solution for such a trivial concept: center this layout group.  BTW The latest post has two weight= lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this layout and modify as per your requirement and if any problem then let me know ...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/btnarea">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selectedWPs"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ae6633"
            android:text="Selected: "
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonArea"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/quitBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="63dp"
                android:background="#990000"
                android:onClick="quitBtnClicked"
                android:text="Quit"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/copyBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:background="#009900"
                android:onClick="copyBtnClicked"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Copy"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't do as required.  See images above.